# EJB3.1 classpath issue

Tags: glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have 2 POJOs, in which one of them is an EJB and the other is a helper class.

```
//EJB Bean class
    @Singleton
    @LocalBean
    @Startup
    public class EJBBean{
     @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
            helper.init();
        }
    } 
//Helper class
public class HelperClass{
      private static Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog("HelperClass");
      private static Long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

     public void init(){
       //Some statements that use Log and do other Initialization
     }
}
```

When I deploy this EJB jar I am getting an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

I have the `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` in the classpath; also, I have configured it to use Log4J. As a standalone app that is without EJB meta-data it works fine. Am I missing some EJB config?

BTW I am pretty new to EJB. I am using GlassFish 3.1, Eclipse Helios as IDE and EJB3.1.

Comment: Where exactly did you put `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`?

Comment: I have folder,Third Party, at the same level of source(ejbModule) folder. This folder contains all libraries required to run my Application. I have added all these libraries to the build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because you put the `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` into the wrong directory or because your server already provides server-wide library which consists of logging classes.

By the way - I remember a lot of strange 'NoClassDefFoundError' because of mixing commons-logging, log4j and slf4j (especially in mismatching versions).

Comment: Thank you for your response. In a standalone mode it is working well and fine. This happens only when I create an EJB jar

Comment: By standalone do you mean an embedded EJB Container?

Comment: Nope I have written a Main method in a separate class and main method in it. It worked well and fine, I mean no issues

Comment: Than you controlled the classpath by your own, right? Now when you're on the Application Server it might provide some server-wide lirbaries which doesn't 'like' your commons-logging. Maybe you should check what libraries are there?

Comment: Where is that I need to check for these libraries?

Comment: Ya fine I got to know where I need to check for Application libs

Comment: I got to know where the problem but I dont know how to solve it.As @Tom Anderson questioned me. The EJB jar file that I am deploying doesnt add any of the Third party Libs in to the classpath, hence it is giving ClassNotFoundException. Can you please help me by suggesting me where to keep these jar files?

Comment: You can try adding the commons-logging-1.1.1.jar on the applications server classpath i.e. glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib

Comment: Is this ok? Because I have around 12 third party libs

Comment: I thought you were talking only about commons-logging which seems to fit the server-wide libraries. I'm not sure if EJB specification mandates that the EJB container must find libraries within ejb-jar module. Typically such EJB-jar's are put into EAR or WAR in which the application (which consists of many ejb-modules and perhaps a web module) put the required libraries

Comment: Your solution has indeed worked. I have added all those libs which are required by the app in the Lib Folder and it worked fine. Later on after finishing with the development of all other Modules will create war file.Thank you very much PedroKowalski

Comment: No problem. @Phani you can take a look at EJB 3.1 specification (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) at chapter 20. Packaging. It might give you some information